# A method that sets multiple data files

Tags: class, oop, methods, get, set

I am just learning Object oriented programming, and this is the assignment I was just given:

*"Design a class named Book that holds a stock number, author, title, price, and number of pages for a book. Include **a method** that sets **all** the data files and another that prints the values for each data field. Create the class diagram and write the pseudocode that defines the class."*

(keep in mind i'm not writing code for a specific language as I know none)
I created the 5 attributes as requested:

---

```
-stockNumber: num
-price: num
-pageCount: num
-author: string
-title: string
```

---

Now I need to create **a single method** that sets all data at once. This is what is tripping me up.

Is there a common way to handle this in one method? or did my teacher mistype, and is it better to have multiple set methods?

Comment: Isn't it Constructor ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A method that sets all data fields at once will most probably be a [*constructor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29), which in UML is just an operation with the same name as the class (and with all the required arguments), that has no return type - for an example, see the first diagram in this PDF: http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring10/V22.0101-003/CircleUML.pdf.

> It [A constructor] prepares the new object for use, **often accepting parameters that the constructor uses to set member variables required**.

A class can have multiple constructors. Given your use case (in the context of a book inventory management application I presume), it seems reasonable for an object *Book* to require all five attributes at instantiation time.

It is, however, not required for a constructor to set all attributes. On the contrary, a couple of Frameworks (e.g. JavaBeans) explicitly require a default constructor without any arguments to be present.

Comment: That term was new to me, I was able to search for the section on _constructors_ in my reading and found the rest of the information I needed. _"In object-oriented programming (OOP) languages, you can write
both default and nondefault constructors, but if you do not create either, then a default constructor is created automatically by the compiler for every class you write."_ I wish my instructor would have assigned this reading, or taught us this before he asked for this assignment.